# Android Scrollview Not working inside Drawer Layout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, drawerlayout

I have Scroll view inside Custom Drawer Layout The scroll view not working.
The view consists of relative layout of image slider and linear layout filled row by row later. Although the property of the height is wrap_content it doesn't work.
Here's the layout xml file`

```
<com.example.msamy.almishkah.HomePage.MyDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/scrollFView">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                    android:id="@+id/slider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    custom:selected_color="#ffa500"
                    custom:selected_height="10dp"
                    custom:selected_padding_left="4dp"
                    custom:selected_padding_right="4dp"
                    custom:selected_width="10dp"
                    custom:shape="rect"
                    custom:unselected_color="#ffffff"
                    custom:unselected_height="10dp"
                    custom:unselected_padding_left="4dp"
                    custom:unselected_padding_right="4dp"
                    custom:unselected_width="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textSlider"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sliderButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="140dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="#ffa500"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/Homeisa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_sliding_menu"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice">

    </ListView>
</com.example.msamy.almishkah.HomePage.MyDrawerLayout>
```

` the relative layout is for image slider in the top of the page and the Layout below is filled pro-grammatically with linear layouts which is bigger than the height of the page.the list view is for the sliding menu of the drawer layout.

Comment: put your scrollview inside a linear layout.

Comment: When putting scroll view inside a linear layout the part under the slider disappears.